# sql merge replication trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

Dear all as i am using SQL merge replication in OLTP environment in which there is about 2 publishers and 28 subscribers. One row has been replicated from one subscriber to another subscriber.

i just wanna trace its time of replication. can any one help me out how can i trace its date and time of replication.

```
SELECT *  FROM [subscriber2].[Databae_name].[schema_name].book_rack c WHERE book_no = ABCDEF
UNION all
SELECT *  FROM [subscriber1].[Databae_name].[schema_name].book_rack c WHERE book_no = ABCDEF
```

Comment: just add a GETDATE() column?

Comment: sir thanks for you kind advise but all data has been replicated. how can i add column against replicated rows?? for future your advise will be consider.

Comment: How do you add a column to a table? `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname [type]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine

Comment: Do you really want a "trace" or are you trying to record the data in a table? Because a SQL "trace" is very different than an audit log.